# How to convert grid to vector in SAGA?

Tags: raster, saga, vector-grid, raster-conversion

I need to convert raster to vector, I have data from a field in two layers. In the first i have DSM (digital surface model) and DTM (digital terain model) in the second layer. Based on difference in those
layers I see areas damaged by animals.

The program I use is SAGA.

The differences are light blue areas in attached images.

How can I convert these areas to vector?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d46e8.jpg

Comment: Have a look at the Module Vectorising Grid Classes

Comment: I tried and I get too many polygons, the program becomes very slow and the field is black. I will try change some parameters and see if it is better. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

As commented by [JonasV](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/157379/jonasv), **Vectorising Grid Classes** is the tool.

Adding to that, you would need to reclassify your grid so that the tool can identify the class to vectorize.

---

A workflow I would suggest:

Let's say I have a grid which background value is 0 (yellow) and the objects (red~ light blue) are represented by positive value (up to 16.2195).

[image]

(1) Start **Reclassify Grid Values** tool (Geoprocessing > Grid > Values)

Select `simple table` as the reclassifying method, and set the look-up table. Remember the class number (in my case it is `2`) which correspond to the objects' value range.

[image]

(2) Start **Vectorising Grid Values** tool (Geoprocessing > Shapes > Shapes-Grid Tools > Vectorization)

Select `one single class specified by class identifier` and set `class identifier`.

[image]

(3) You will obtain the polygons (multi-polygons) encompass the designated grid class.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works!

Comment: You can accept the answer to show that your question has been solved